# How to select very small components in an image

Tags: image-processing, image

I have been trying to identify the centroids or positions of the small yellow dots (not the large regions) in the image below. I have adopted the following strategy (please see the code), however, i wonder if the results can be improved. In my attempt, I could not identify all spots and rather some extraneous spots are also selected. Thanks !

The original picture:

[image]

The picture with the centroids of the spots highlighted, is as follows:

[image]

The code can be found below:

```
segmented = ColorSeparate[img][[2]] // MorphologicalPerimeter[#, 0.2] & // MorphologicalComponents //
SelectComponents[#, {"Count", "AdjacentBorderCount","Holes"}, #1 < 50 && #2 == 0 && #3 >=  0 &] & 
// Colorize

centroids = ComponentMeasurements[segmented, "Centroid"];
HighlightImage[img, ListPlot[centroids // Values]]
```

Also do you recommend the use of `Binarize[img]` in the very beginning?

Answer (score 3):

I will recommend a function of `TopHatTransform` for this request,you wil get it like this:

```
mask = MaxDetect[TopHatTransform[img, DiskMatrix[1]], .2]
```

[image]

Show it in your original picture:

```
HighlightImage[img, {Gray, mask}]
```

[image]